# How to sum only the first two values of an array?

Tags: arrays, swift

inputArray = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

a) sum only 3 & 6 (that will be the first two values)

b) sum the result of 3 and 6 with -2.

c) I want to sum the first 2, multiply them with the third, skip the fourth and sum the last 2.

Thanks, I want to learn how to do it.

Challenge: https://app.codesignal.com/arcade/intro/level-2/xzKiBHjhoinnpdh6m

Comment: What is “apply the concept to all the array“? What is the desired output?

Comment: I'm not sure how the process you're describing differs at all from just summing the whole thing at once.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery because the solution is to sum 2 and then skip and then sum 2 again.

Comment: @Jessy summing 2, skip and then summing 2 again over all the array.

Comment: @Marlhex I don't see anything in the question about skipping numbers.

Comment: Following the a/b/c steps you laid out, if you add the first two, then add the third to that sum, and so on, the final sum will be exactly the same as if you added them all at once.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I want to learn how to manipulate the iteration within an array. Meaning: If I want to sum the first two values and then multiply them with the third. And then sum the last 2. This is based on this challange https://app.codesignal.com/arcade/intro/level-2/xzKiBHjhoinnpdh6m

Comment: An arbitrary chain of different operations isn't really something you can do cleanly with a loop or iterator, you're better off just using the array indices directly at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```swift
inputArray[0 ..< 2].reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: I would recommend `inputArray.predix(2).reduce(0, +)` instead. It's clearer to read (IMO), and doesn't crash if the input array is empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a loop, you can track the progress over each iteration. For example:

```
var currentSum = 0
let inputArray = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]
for item in inputArray {
    currentSum += item
    print(currentSum)
}
```